# JS:processing forms with missing/optional data

Tags: javascript

preface: I'm not a programmer or even web developer. I'm a print designer with just enough info to be dangerous. so, please don't assume I know something basic ;-)

I'm working on an in-house form to generate HTML for the non-HTMLers in our office. It's just a basic form that takes data entry and concatenates it together inside the proper HTML.

problem is not all of the field entries are required. but, the way it is working currently it just assumes data present.

hopefully this is a basic issue. but, I need to insert some logic in to the concatenation portion of the javascript that ignores null fields.

here's a working snippet of what I'm talking about:

http://devtest.host.org/testing/sample-form.html

of course, the actual form has 25 or so fields. but, i've simplified it here to make my point: suppose only one bullet is entered in the form. I need to be able to tell the variable "text" to omit the second set of

```
<LI> </LI>
```

tags since there is no 2nd bullet data.

if someone has some suggestions on how to approach this issue I'd appreciate it.

thanks.

[edit: added codeblock]

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Parent Category HTML Generator</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body {
background-color:white;
}
label, textarea {
display:block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
document.getElementById('product').onsubmit=function() {
 var Main_Image=document.getElementById('Main_Image').value;
 var Bullet1=document.getElementById('Bullet1').value;
 var Bullet2=document.getElementById('Bullet2').value;


var text="<img src=\"assets/images/"+Main_Image+"\"><br><ul><li>"+Bullet1+"</li><li>"+Bullet2+"</li></ul>";
document.getElementById('code').value=text;
return false;
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="product" action="#">
Filename: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" TABINDEX="1" size="40" id="Main_Image"><BR>
Bullet 1: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" TABINDEX="3" size="50" id="Bullet1"><BR>
Bullet 2: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" TABINDEX="4" size="50" id="Bullet2"><BR>
<BR>

<input type="submit">
</form>
<BR><BR>

<p>HTML:</p>
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="code"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does your form generate DOM elements, or a html string that users can copy/paste?

Comment: added codeblock to original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take this approach:

```
var Main_Image_present = Main_Image.length > 0;
var Bullet1_present = Bullet1.length > 0;
var Bullet2_present = Bullet2.length > 0;
var text= '';
if(Main_Image_present)
  text += '<img src="assets/images/'+Main_Image+'"><br>';
if(Bullet1_present || Bullet2_present) {
  text += '<ul>';
  if(Bullet1_present)
    text += '<li>'+Bullet1+'</li>';
  if(Bullet2_present)
    text += '<li>'+Bullet2+'</li></ul>';
  text += '</ul>';
}
```

Basically this just checks the length on the values of the inputs.  It only adds the necessary HTML if the value is present (or length > 0).

Comment: this looks really good. i will take this approach and see how it goes. thanks.

Comment: took a few minutes to go through all 25 variables. but, this worked great! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution would be to add post-processing and remove empty nodes (for example `<li></li>`) from your text variable. But it won't work for more complex cases (e.g. your image).

I'd suggest that you break your string into multiple steps, as follows:

```
var text=(Main_Image?"<img src=\"assets/images/"+Main_Image+"\"><br>":"")+
         "<ul>"+
         (Bullet1?"<li>"+Bullet1+"</li>":"")+
         (Bullet2?"<li>"+Bullet2+"</li>":"")+
         "</ul>";
```

(condition?choice1:choice2) will select choice1 if condition is true, choice2 if not. In your case the condition is simply to know whether the string is not empty.